# Consider a game that consists of dealing out three hands of three cards each from a deck of nine cards. (calculating probability help)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a game that consists of dealing out three hands of three cards each from a deck of nine cards. The deck contains the three Aces, three Kings, and three Queens.

Let the random variable X denote the number of hands containing Aces. Find the expected value of X.

Number of hands that can have an ace = [1,2,3]

Thus, we want

P(1 hand gets all 3 aces)

P(1 hand gets two aces 1 hand gets one ace)

P(each hand gets one ace)

Now this is where this gets iffy for me..

P(1 hand gets 3 aces) = ((3 choose one ways to pick the hand that gets the 3 aces)(3 choose 3 ways to put the aces in first hand) / (9 choose 3 total combinations) ) x (6 choose 3 ways to pick 3 cards in second hand)/(9 choose 3 total) x (3 choose 3 ways to pick 3 cards in third hand)/ (9 choose 3 ways total)

or [${3 \choose 1} {3 \choose 3} / {9 \choose 3}]   [{6 \choose 3}/{9 \choose 3}]   [{3 \choose 3}/{9 \choose 3}]$

P(1 hand gets two aces 1 hand gets one ace) = I don't even know where to begin

P(each hand gets one ace) = ((3 choose 1 ways to pick first ace) (6 choose 2 ways to pick next two cards)/ (9 choose 3 total) ) ((2 choose 1 ways to pick second ace) ( 4 choose 2 ways to pick other two cards) / (9 choose 3))
(1 choose 1 ways to pick last ace) (2 choose 2 ways to pick two other cards) / (9 choose 3 total ways))

or $[{3 \choose 1} {6 \choose 2} / {9 \choose 3}]   [{2 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2} / {9 \choose 3}]   [ {1 \choose 1} {2 \choose 2} / {9 \choose 3}]$

If someone could help me finish getting the p values that would be amazing I'm so lost at counting rules.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (setting you free from the counting rules):

Number the hands with $1,2,3$ and for $i=1,2,3$ let $H_i$ take value $1$ if hand $i$ contains aces and let $H_i$ take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $H=H_1+H_2+H_3$ is exactly the number of hands that contain aces.

Now apply linearity of expectation and symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about this independent of "hands," - rather - think of permutations of the 9 cards as giving you your hands (e.g. the first three cards go to player 1, the next three to player 2, and so on).

Now, you're being asked a question about counting the number of permutations that:

(1) place three aces in positions (1-3), (4-6), or (7-9).

Of which, there are $3*6!$

(2) place two aces in (1-3), (4-6), or (7-9), and one ace not in this interval.

begin by placing the aces in the interval any of three ways (A,A,X),(A,X,A) or (X,A,A), where X is not an ace. There are 6 choices for each X, resulting in $3*3*6*6!$ ways to place the aces.

(3) one ace in each interval.

Choose any one index in each interval, and assign an ace to that index. There are $3^3$ ways to choose the indices, and $6!$ ways to deal the remaining cards.

Dividing each of these by 9! should give the desired result, assuming all cards are distinguishable.

Comment: Will that give the same answer as the counting rules way I did it?

Comment: I got a different answer than the one you said using counting rules